# 'PERSISTENT' variable present in window object of Microsoft Edge, But not in Mozilla Firefox. why?

Tags: javascript, object, firefox, microsoft-edge

'PERSISTENT' variable present in window object of Microsoft Edge, But not in Mozilla Firefox. Default value is 1, What is this variable for ??

```
//In Microsoft Edge
console.log(typeof(PERSISTENT)); //Number
console.log(PERSISTENT); //1`enter code here`

//In Mozilla Firefox
console.log(typeof(PERSISTENT)); //undefined
console.log(PERSISTENT); //Uncaught ReferenceError: PERSISTENT is not defined
```

Explanation If Any ?

Comment: I'm in favor of Kaiido's opinion. From the [doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/requestFileSystem), we can know that *only Chrome implements it, and all other browser makers have decided that they will not implement it. It has even been removed from the proposed specification.* That's why it is undefined in Firefox. The new Edge is based on Chromium so it can use this API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an enum from a [non-standard file system API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/requestFileSystem) that Chromium did develop.

It goes in pair with the `window.TEMPORARY` enum, and is used as the `type` parameter of `window.requestFileSystem(type, size, successCallback[, errorCallback]);`

---

Note that this API is being replaced by the [Native File System API](https://wicg.github.io/native-file-system/), which doesn't use these enums anymore.